# Cannot write to custom event log

Tags: c#, event-log, eventlog-source, custom-eventlog

I have created a simple Windows service.
The service registers a custom event source and log.
For testing purposes I have named the log "asd" and the source ".asd".
Both the log and source are correctly created, the service is correctly installed and it is running fine.
However the log cannot be written to. No error or exception is thrown, just nothing happens.
I use the `eventLog.WriteEntry` method, where `eventLog` is the name of the service `System.Diagnostics.EventLog` component.
However nothing is written to said event log, even though I know the method executes and, at least, no exception is thrown so I surmise it has finished successfully.
I have tried writing to the log by starting Powershell as Administrator and using the `Write-EventLog` cmdlet, which works just fine if writing to, say, the Application log (with an appropriate source) but nothing happens if I use it to write to the custom "asd" log - no entry appears in Windows' Event Viewer even after refresh or restart of the Event Viewer.
Tried restarting the Windows Event Logging service but it fails due to having to also restart the Task Scheduler service, which is not accessible by the built-in Administrator account, because I'm using Windows 7 and it is stupid.

I *was* able to write to the custom event log a few builds ago but reverting fixes nothing and I haven't made **any** changes related to that.

Any help or ideas why I can't write to that log would be appreciated!

Comment: have you still not overcome this? if yes, have you checked if the log actually got created in **C:\Windows\System32\Winevt\Logs\** ?

Comment: @kowsikbabu, thanks for stumbling onto my question! I'll try it when I get the chance, but currently I am on another topic, entirely, so it will be some time before I do. :)